Loop cut scale not working
I made a loop cut in the middle of a four sided cube, and am trying to scale it inwards by selecting the bottom side with Face select and scale it inwards. But for some reason, it is instead acting like I am moving it, and not scaling.


As you can see in your screenshot, the dashed black line connects to somewhere higher up outside the image. This line usually connects to the pivot point of a rotation or scaling operation - so it is not scaling around the Median Point of the face. It looks like it is using the 3D Cursor. This is why I linked the other question above, there the problem was a changed Transformation Pivot Point.

Thanks sir, this helped a lot
